# Problems in user - registration module in DRUPAL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-fapi, user-registration, drupal-alter

I have some problem in drupal registration page.

1. I want to change whole user registration page. in registration module i want to add new field type. Bcz i want that user can choose the date from date-time picker. I have ready date-time picker which i have implement, but i don't know where to put that code.
2. I want to add validation on new added text fields. Means i have added one text field for Phone no, so now i want to check if user had only entered the numbers.....in new user registration page.

Thanks in advance

---

Nitish

Comment: You may also be interested in the Content Profile module, which allows you to use Nodes and CCK for user information. http://drupal.org/project/content_profile

Comment: You may also be interested in the core Profile module. try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alter the way user registration works, you can do it with `hook_form_alter` on the registration form.

With the [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module, you can insert a form field that has a jQuery popup date picker.

The `$form['#validate']` is an array of validation functions to call, you can add your own to the list to run your own validation.